# My code doesnt read the defined constants in PHP

Tags: php, constants

Hi All
 I have a project working in PHP which is divided in an admin section and client section.

Client ecd is working perfectly fine. But I Cannot access my admin section and it displays the error saying

> Fatal error: Class 'ClsBase' not found in E:\wamp\www\dfms\admin\index.php on line 30

**UPDATE**

line 28 is `$base_obj = new ClsBase();`

**UPDATE1**

LINE 14:include_once(ADMIN_CLASS_DIR ."ClsAdminUser.php");

But I have defined all the constants in my `adminconfig.php` And I am using the Constant to give the path to this file and also this file present in the required folder

Could you please help me What could be the problem?

Comment: Can you post the code? What is shown if you print the const?

Comment: So the login file is located somewhere other than E:\wamp\www\dfms\admin\login.php... Please post the PHP code which calls the file.

Comment: it just prints me "ADMIN_CLASS_DIR"

Comment: If the const is not set thats exactly what you would get. PHP assumes it to be a string if the const is not available. However you should get a notice ( / warning dont know which one) about it.

Comment: The constant is accessed before the adminconfig.php was included. That's it.

Comment: I love these users being afraid of showing their code out. Dudes, we need codes or how the hell are we supposed to solve this? Guessing? Also, the error is in line 30 and you post line 28 / 14? Ok, i can guess what's on line 30 but wth! Nobody will steal your code!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without seeing code, it's hard to tell.  There are two possible problems.

1. `ADMIN_CLASS_DIR` is not set, so PHP will issue a `notice` and default to `ADMIN_CLASS_DIR`.  Your code would look like:

   ```
    include_once(ADMIN_CLASS_DIR . 'ClsAdminUser.php');
   ```

   To fix it, just define the directory:

   ```
    if (!defined('ADMIN_CLASS_DIR')) {
        define('ADMIN_CLASS_DIR', 'path/to/dir');
    }
   ```
2. You're trying to use it inside of a string literal:

   ```
   include_once('ADMIN_CLASS_DIR/ClsAdminUser.php');
   ```

   Constants in PHP don't work like that.  They are only resolved outside of a string.  So you could do either:

   ```
   include_once(ADMIN_CLASS_DIR . '/ClsAdminUser.php');
   ```

   Or you could do this if you needed to define the constant as a string:

   ```
   include_once(constant('ADMIN_CLASS_USER') . '/ClsAdminUser.php');
   ```

To tell if the constant is defined, use the [`defined`](https://www.php.net/defined) function.  It'll return `true` if the constant is defined.

If you want better help than that, post some code!

Comment: I Have posted the code line where I am getting the error pls see the update

Comment: @OmThe: What's the code at line 14 of login.php as indicated by the warning (*in E:\wamp\www\dfms\admin\login.php on line 14*)?  The code you posted isn't directly relevant to the problem...

Comment: @ircmaxell Its main issue is that it cannot find the class file on but i have the files at the required location

Comment: @OMT: Post line 14 which is where the warning is telling you the problem is.  Better yet, change `include_once` to `require_once`, since you need it to continue (But still post the line).

Comment: Is there any Problem in my WAMP settings? as the same code was working in my other machine in office

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you expect a constant `ADMIN_CLASS_DIR` to be set, when it's not. PHP will issue a notice and then assume that the constant is a string literal. Where do you define this constant? You need to include that code in your script.

Comment: This is the admin section where I am facing this problem, ON THE CONTRARY, My client section(Front End) is working perfectly fine, and on other machine there was no such error.

Comment: Most likely, the `include_path` is different on the other machine.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you didn't define the constant before you got to the codeblock which uses it.

You should get a notice though:

```
Notice:  Use of undefined constant ADMIN_CLASS_DIR - assumed 'ADMIN_CLASS_DIR'
```

This states that PHP will assume it is a string. And treats it this way.

Disclaimer / Offtopic:

PHP really has some weird issues

Comment: it just prints me "ADMIN_CLASS_DIR"

Comment: Can you show code? I think you didn't set your constant / is not available where you try to use it.